# python pysnmp use list of oids in getbulk

Tags: python, snmp, pysnmp

Hi all im looking for a solution to get multiple oids at the same time.
for example is it possible to use list of oids in pysnmp get command generator?

from this:

```
cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBindTable = cmdGen.bulkCmd(
    cmdgen.CommunityData('public'),
    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
    0, 25,
    '1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2',
    '1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.3',
)
```

to something like:

```
myoid = ['1.3.6.1.2.1.1.1.0', '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0', '1.3.6.1.2.1.1.6.0']

cmdGen = cmdgen.CommandGenerator()

errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBindTable = cmdGen.bulkCmd(
    cmdgen.CommunityData('public'),
    cmdgen.UdpTransportTarget(('demo.snmplabs.com', 161)),
    0, 25,
    myoids,
)
```

the actual problem is the oids are variables so im looking for a way to change them easily.

Answer (score 6):

Sure, just pass it *myoids (note the asterisk).